# Changing ip address of the domains A record

Tags: dns, subdomain, cpanel

I've a strange requirement for one of my domains and I don't know how can I achieve it.

I have a domain (lets assume its xyz.com) and the domain and all of its subdomains are hosted in 1.2.3.4 ip address with using channel
My current configuration of the domain is

xyz.com -> A -> 1.2.3.4
sub.xyz.com -> A -> xyz.com

What I want to achieve here is: I want to change my domains ip address to point another ip(assume its 5.6.7.8) but subdomains(sub.xyz.com) to show the old ip address(1.2.3.4)
Is something like that possible?

If it is how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the two A records as such:

```
A record xyz.com -> 5.6.7.8
(and probably www.xyz.com -> 5.6.7.8)
A record sub.xyz.com -> 1.2.3.4
```

That should do the trick.